# How to pass Multiline Subject line to find Certificate or in Command line

Tags: certificate, x509certificate

I used to give Certificate name to the some command line tools like `certmgr.exe` or `FindPrivateKey.exe` etc like this.

`certmgr -del -r LocalMachine -s TrustedPeople -c -n "CN=localhost"`
I this case the Subject only one like `"CN=localhost"`.

Now the problem is that I am getting a Certificate with multiline Subject.

[image]

How to give that long, multiline Subject name in Command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject is a collection of field-value pairs like CN, Country, State etc.

You can run this command to insert it one after the other when the cmd prompts you to

> openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout
>   mycert.pem -out mycert.pem

Else, to insert it straight away in the commandline without having to enter it during the prompt each time, you can run this

> openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -subj
>   "/C=CA/ST=ON/L=Toronto/CN=www.thetechdown.blogspot.ca" -newkey
>   rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem

Answer (score 2):

Subject is not multiline. It's not a string at all. Subject is a complex structure with several fields. This structure is rendered to a string for presentation purposes. Normally tools that accept subject as a string would parse fields separated with coma, eg. `"CN=XXX, OU=YYY ZZZ, C=US"`

Comment: I tried this `FindPrivateKey.exe TrustedPeople CurrentUser -n "CN=XXXXX, Inc., OU=Digital ID Class 3 - Microsoft Software Validation v2, O=peerVue, Inc., L=Sarasota, S=Florida, C=US"` .... Not working

Comment: @Sreekumar I can't say about particular third-party tools. Maybe you need to specify just one field (eg. "CN=XXXXX, Inc.") for searching.

Comment: but I also tried `certmgr.exe` like this `certmgr -del -r LocalMachine -s TrustedPeople -c -n "CN=XXXXX, Inc., OU=Digital ID Class 3 - Microsoft Software Validation v2, O=peerVue, Inc., L=Sarasota, S=Florida, C=US"` that too is not working. `certmgr.exe` is a Tool with Visual Studio Tools

Comment: Did you try specifying just CN as I mentioned in the previous comment? Signtool.exe, btw, accepts parameters as follows: `SPC /n "EldoS Corporation"`, i.e. only the common name value is passed. And if you read documentation for certmgr.exe, you'll see that you need to specify the value of the common name, i.e. just "XXXXX, Inc."

Comment: From the doc: /n commonName String

Specifies the *common* name of the certificate to add, delete, or save. This option can only be used with certificates; it cannot be used with CTLs or CRLs.